# custom taxonomies label in hebrew

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to add a custom taxonomy.
using the following code:

```
    function cities_custom_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'city', // internal name = machine-readable taxonomy name
        'post', // object type = post, page, link, or custom post-type
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false, // true for hierarchical like cats, false for flat like tags
            'label' => 'City', // the human-readable taxonomy name
            'query_var' => true, // enable taxonomy-specific querying
            'rewrite' => true // pretty permalinks for your taxonomy?
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'cities_custom_taxonomies', 0);
```

As long as I use label name in English, all works fine. Once I try to label it in Hebrew, I don't see the new taxonomy menu.
any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap the english label name with the translation function `__( 'City', 'textdomain' )`, and put the hebrew version in your translation file.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers